# How to display an array made in "AddRecipe file" to "InstructionsView" file in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, xcode, class, variables, swiftui

I have made an empty array called "instructions" in a file called "AddRecipe" and I have used a TextField and Button to append items to it. But now I want to display this array in another file called "InstructionsView".How do I do that? I have tried several things but none seem to work.

This is the AddRecipe file

```
class instructionsArray: ObservableObject {
       @Published var instructions: [String] = []
}

struct AddRecipe: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@ObservedObject var data = instructionsArray()
```

This is the InstructionsView file

```
struct InstructionsView: View {

@ObservedObject var data = instructionsArray()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
            ForEach(data.instructions, id: \.self) { i in
                Text(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)